# How do I prove that Gateaux differential is linear

Tags: functional-analysis, gateaux-derivative

Reference:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative
('Linearity and continuity' section)

Let $V,W$ be Banach spaces over $\mathbb{K}$ and $E$ be open in $V$.

Let $f:E\rightarrow W$ be a function which is Gateaux-differentiable at $p$. That is, $\forall h\in V, \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(p+th)-f(p)}{t}$ exists.

Let $df(p;h)$ denote the Gateaux-differential of $f$ at $p$ in the direction $h$.

Define $F(h)=df(p;h)$ for all $h\in V$.

How do I prove that $F$ is linear?

Here's how I tried:

Fix $h,k\in V$ and define $g(t,s)=f(p+th+sk)$ where $s,t$ are (real)complex numbers. Then, $g_t(0,0)=df(p;h)$ and $g_s(0,0)=df(p;k)$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{g(t,t)-g(0,0)}{t}=df(p;h+k)$. In general, $g$ is differentiable along any **straight line** passing through the origin.

Since I don't know the continuity of $g$, I cannot find a relation among the above equalities..

Please help.. Thank you in advance

Comment: @WillJagy "Nevertheless, for functions F from a complex Banach space X to another complex Banach space Y, the Gâteaux derivative (where the limit is taken over complex τ tending to zero as in the definition of complex differentiability) is automatically linear, a theorem of Zorn (1945)." - Wikipedia

Comment: @WillJagy As it says, I think it's true for Banach spaces..

Comment: @WillJagy I'm reading Giovanni's a primer or non linear analysis, **but** this text gives the definition of Gateaux derivative as a continuous linear operator. However, I'm using only the term defined in wikipedia for this post. (That is, Gateaux differential in your comment)

Comment: Edited {}{}{}{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIFFERENTIATING AT THE ORIGIN.

Take the vector space to be the ordinary $(x,y)$ plane. In polar coordinates, restricting to $r \geq 0,$ let
$$ f(r, \theta) = r \sin 3 \theta .  $$ A line through the origin is given by fixing a value of $\theta;$ doing so, the Gateaux ratio is just the constant $\sin 3 \theta ,$ so that is also the limit.

The Gateaux ratio is $0$ in linearly independent directions, angles $0,\pi/3. $ If it were linear, we would always get the Gateaux ratio being $0.$ But that is not the case. So, not linear.

Oh, we need the $3$ to be odd to get correct comparison between $\theta$ and $\theta + \pi.$ If we replaced the $3$ by $1,$ we would have $f = y,$ differentiable in every sense.

Comment: At which point are you differentiating $f$?

Comment: $(0,0)$ is not in the domain then.. $(0,0)\notin \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I'm sorry if I annoy you, but if $r≧0$, then the domain is not open

Comment: @Rubertos Translate into Cartesian coordinates, $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\quad 0 &, x = y = 0 \\ \frac{3x^2y - y^3}{x^2+y^2} &, x^2 + y^2 > 0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh.. So the real case is false. However, it's stated in wikipedia that it is linear for complex Banach spaces. How do I prove that?? Please help me.. I think it's better to post another one for this. Thank you and Will, I didn't mean to harass you. I'm sorry if you got annoyed

Comment: @Rubertos If you only have the complex Gâteaux derivative at one point (in all directions, however), I don't know the proof, maybe you need to look at Zorn's original paper. If you have complex Gâteaux differentiability on an open set, it's an easy consequence of Hartogs' theorem. You only need to consider the case where the domain is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ in any case, maybe that simplifies things enough.